# edmx updates from the wrong database

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

i have 2 databases old and new they have the same structure.

in the edmx file i updated by mistake the

> update model from database

to the wrong database and now i dont know how to change to the new database -i remember that i had a windows where i inserted the database name and afterwards it gave me this window as in the image - now i have this image right away and no window that asks me what database i need[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the connection string from the *app.config* and re-run the *Update from Database* assistant. It'll show that window again.

Answer (score 0):

In **config** file(App.config) change database connection string

Answer (score 0):

Go to your application Web.Config file, find the connection string that is using your model and update it to target to your new database instead:

```
<add name="Resources" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\;initial catalog=**YOUR_DB_NAME**;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```